# How to make play/stop buttons for iframe audio?

Tags: audio, iframe, playback, pause

I need to make audio players from soundcloud links, which can't be played by audio element, they need an iframe.
I found a lot of tutorials how to make custom play/stop buttons for iframe video. Unfortunately they don't work for iframe audio. Is there a way to make those buttons for iframe audio, too?

Answer (score 0):

Soundcloud embed links displays as player with play or pause button. https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed

Comment: I suggest you to write to soundcloud support